# Android Studio 3.1 is not adding Volley on my dependencies, Any ideas why?

Tags: android-volley

Why Android Studio 3.1 is not adding Volley on my dependencies, Any ideas why?

The **compile** configuration is deprecated: compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

Here is the error I get when I use the new **Implementation** configuration: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0.

Same applies for **api** configuration

Comment: Did you find a solution to it ? I am using AS 3.2 but I get the same error for     api 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

Comment: Yes I did find a Solution.  I went down to the containing folder of Android studio and added a downloaded .gradle file from internet   :  C:\Users\myAccount\.gradle\wrapper\dists